# How do I resolve a merge conflict when both server and local versions are wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am working in the enterprise on Visual Studio 2013 and Team Foundation Server. We have a test source and a production source, and I Get Latest on them both regularly. As there are only a few developers, we make changes  directly in test, we don't have personal branches off of test (though when our shop was bigger, we did).

So I opened a file in Test, made a simple change to it, saved it, checked it into test, and published it to production. When I went to merge Test with production, I spawned a merge conflict. I am looking at the "server" version and the "local" version and neither one is correct. The "server" version is the file I edited, minus the edit I just made. That makes sense. But the "local" version is something I haven't seen before, what looks like perhaps an older version that I've never never worked on. Maybe this was my local copy and Get Latest didn't update it. But the local file I edited was exactly what I expected it to be.

So, what could cause that? How do I troubleshoot this problem? All I want is to get the correct version in TFS so it doesn't get blown away later, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Test and Production are separate branches?  If you haven't checked in any of the merge stuff yet. I would undo any local changes, get latest on both branches, then try the merge again.

Comment: Undo you changes on your test file...got latest version, then  go to your production branch, and merge it with test...check in the changes on test, edit the file and merge it with prod....

Comment: My changes are checked into test, as I had no reason to suspect a problem. Does that make a difference? Can I still undo changes even if it is checked in?

Answer (score 0):

This may due to when you do the get latest option, TFS didn't update the workspace correctly.

A clean way to do this, back up your file with changes, undo your pending changes. Delete the old workspace, create a new one. Get latest version from server for both test and production  source.

Edit the specific file with changes, check it into the test, and finally do the merge Test with production again.